# Getting gpio pinctrl value in Linux during Runtime

Tags: linux, gpio, device-driver

I know that a Gpio pin can be configured to several alternate functions (i2c, uart,...) via the [pinctrl subsystem](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/pinctl.html). that could be configured in the Device tree. Now I want to read the function assigned to a specific pin on Runtime, I take a look at `/proc/sys/class/gpio` but the information seems not to be there, Does anyone has a hint ?

Comment: There is no such interface. Some of the controllers, for example Intel ones, may provide a debug information available through debugs from where it's possible to **decode** what you need. **Decode** becuase it will be raw register value and you have to have known which bits are corresponds to what you need. Again, on Intel there is a specific mode that gets printed directly, a bit easier to parse. Example: `pin 57 (SLP_S0B) 44:INT34C6:00 mode 1 0x44000700 0x00000051 0x00000000 [LOCKED full, ACPI]`.

Comment: Yes, basically all the SoCs should provide this kind of status register, to give the configured Alternate function, but what I noticed is that it is not supported in the device driver, Maybe I need to hack the device driver for my purpose

Comment: Hacking a device driver and upstreaming the change is definitely a win.

Answer (score 2):

pinctl information is avalable under /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/*

To have it avalable your kernel must be configered for debugging and the debugfs must be mounted:

`zcat /proc/config.gz  | grep CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL`

`mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug`